# Why does the execution order of touchesBegan, target-action and touchesEnded change with fast touches of UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

***UPDATE:** With the blush of shame I discovered that the order had nothing to do with the speed of tapping. I was calling the visual code before the super touchesEnded:withEvent call, which was why if you tapped really fast, the display never got a chance to draw the highlighted state before being dismissed again. Because the code that was actually causing the main thread to block just a few milliseconds, the highlighted state would stay visible until the main thread unblocked again, where as if you tapped really fast, it looked like nothing happened at all. Moving the super call up to the top of the overridden method fixed it all. Sorry, if any moderator sees this post it can be deleted. **shame***

This problem must have been asked a 1000 times at SO, yet I can't find the explanation to match my specific issue.

I have a UIButton subclass with a custom design. Of course the design is custom enough that I can't just use the regular `setSomething:forControlState:` methods. I need a different backgroundcolor on touch, for one, and some icons that need to flash.

To implement these view changes, I (counter-intuitively) put the display code in (A) `touchesBegan:withEvent` and (Z) `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, before calling their respective super methods. Feels weird, but it works as intended, or so it seemed at first.

After implementing `addTarget:action:forControlEvents` was used to bind the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` to the method (X) `itemTapped:`, I would expect these methods to always fire in the order (A)(X)(Z). However, if you tap the screen real fast (or the mouse in simulator), they fire in the order (A)(Z)(X). Where (A) and (Z) follow each other in such rapid succession, that the whole visual feedback for tapping is invisible. This is unwanted behavior. This also can't be the way to go, for so many apps need similar behavior, right?

So my question to you is: What am I doing wrong? One thing I'm guessing is that the visual appearance of the buttons shouldn't be manipulated in the `touchesBegan:withEvent` and `touchesEnded:withEvent`, but then where? Or am I missing some other well known fact?

Thanks for the nudge,
Eric-Paul.

Comment: Just curious, if I touch 3 times fast, is the order AZXAZXAZX or something else?

Comment: AZX AZX AZX, very reproducable. The touch up happens before the target-action is triggered, although I thought that that target-action was triggered from the [super touchesEnded:withEvent]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why the order is different, but here's 2 suggestions to help deal with it.

What visual changes are you making to the button? If it's things like changing title/image/background image, you can do all this by modifying the highlighted state of the button. You can set a few properties like title and background image per-state. When the user's finger is down on the button, the `highlighted` state is turned on, so any changes you make to this state will be visible at this time. Do note that if you're making use of the `selected` state on the button, then you'll need to also set up the visual appearance for `UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected`, otherwise it will default back to inheriting from Normal when both highlighted & selected are on.

The other suggestion is to ditch `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and switch over to using the methods inherited from UIControl, namely `beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:` and `endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:`. You may also want to implement `continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:` and use the `touchInside` property to turn off your visual tweaks if the touch leaves the control.

Comment: Thanks for hinting at the beginTracking methods. That was a good insight. However as stated in the update, the reason for the behavior was my interpretation error, not a code error. Sorry!

Comment: Heh, if I get a mere 65 more karma then I'll have the power to delete closed posts... ;)

Comment: Here you have my +1, on to the 10k :) Does it need to be closed?

Comment: Heh, thanks. I think it does, but I'll know for certain when I get the requisite karma.

Comment: @epologee if I close and delete @Kevin loses all the effort he made to help you.

Comment: @Will That's a very good point. Even though your question was resolved on your own, my answer may still hold some information for someone else.

Comment: Hereby marked as resolved. Thanks, you've also crossed the 10k, congrats.